# Spring batch step issue

Tags: spring, spring-batch, spring-jms

SpringJMSListener on receiving the message invokes the spring batch job. It is configured to use DefaultMessageListenerContainer with concurrency of 5 and max concurrency of 15.

Spring batch has job definition of 4 steps that are configured as tasklets.

When there are multiple request submitted, jms listener picks up 5 messages and runs the spring batch.

But occasionally, few jobs takes more time to execute when it moves from one step to another step. Couldnt find any specific reason on why spring batch takes more time from between step execution. That is after the step is completed and before the next step is started. This doesnt happen always.

Any insights on this specific problem?

Comment: what sort of task executor or you using?

Comment: I have left it with default.  So i assume DefaultMessageListener uses AsyncTaskExecutor if iam not wrong.

Comment: And also the Jms container runs inside websphere app server.

Comment: Also noticed, it is not just happening during step hops in batch, the complete request from message picked up until complete is getting slow sporadically.